# Problem about loading a code into UNO board

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

Recently, I have tried to upload an Arduino code into an UNO board. Fortunately, when I verify it, it does not include any error.

However, when I start uploading the code, it indicates an error as shown in the figure:

[image]

Moreover, I don't know too much about Arduino. Therefore, what does this error mean?

Does it mean that the board has a problem, or it's just about my code?

Many thanks.

Comment: You need to tell the ide which serial port to use in the `Tools->Port` menu. In the future, consider posting questions regarding the Arduino at [arduino.se].

Comment: And don't post pictures of error messages.  Post them as text.  Finally, every question that could occur about avrdude is out there on the internet or on specialty forums.  Yours is not a software programming question and doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you need to check what port you are uploading the code to. In this case, the Arduino IDE is trying to upload your code to `COM1`, go to `Tools -> Port` to check what port you are using. Select the one that has the board you want to use (it will say the board name next to the port number in the list).

[image: Screenshot to show where the Port menu is]

It may also be worth checking what board you have selected as well, (to see what board you are uploading to, check the list above the ports list in the tools menu).

Comment: In my environment, I have no Arduino device plugged in to any port, so the ports menu is grey, but in your case when you select the `Port` button, it will appear with a list ports. (You need at least one device plugged in to show the ports list). It's strange that the Arduino environment did not pick your Arduino by default, but not impossible.